# Magento 2 Add track order link popup on admin sales order grid page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Anyone have idea how we can open track order link popup open on the admin sales order grid.

Comment: Do you want to show tracking pop-up on admin side?

Comment: yes @DhirenVasoya I want to add in admin order grid